# Email Address not Appearing in Facebook Graph API Response When Permission is Changed from Friends to Public

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I switched the access permission of my email address from "Friends" to "Public". In the Graph API Explorer, I checked all of the permissions and then got an access token. Then I ran the request

```
"/v2.2/100007513148503?fields=email"
```

but the response was

```
{ "id": "100007513148503" }
```

When I hovered over the email field it said `Field is empty or disallowed by the access token.`, but the access permission is public. How can I get the email address?

Comment: Did the app ask for email permission? And is the email confirmed?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the email of the authorized user, so the ID must be the same as the one of the User Access Token. You can also just use `/me?fields=email` instead of the ID.

Make sure you authorized the user with the email permission, of course. Btw, the visibility setting is irrelevant.